# Factoring the determinant of a product

Tags: linear-algebra

In the proof of Abel's/Liouville's formula, they use

$$\frac{d}{dt}\det \Phi(t) = \left|
\begin{matrix}\phi_{11}' & \phi_{12}' \\
\phi_{21} & \phi_{22}
\end{matrix} \right| + \left| 
\begin{matrix}\phi_{11} & \phi_{12} \\
\phi_{21}' & \phi'_{22}
\end{matrix} \right|$$

Since $A\Phi = \Phi'$, we have $\Phi'_{ij} = \sum_k a_{ik}\phi_{kj}$, so the first term becomes

$$\left| 
\begin{matrix}a_{11}\phi_{11} + a_{21}\phi_{21} & a_{11}\phi_{12}+a_{21}\phi_{22} \\
\phi_{21} & \phi_{22}
\end{matrix} \right|$$

They factor this according to

$$a_{11} \left| 
\begin{matrix}\phi_{11} & \phi_{12} \\
\phi_{21} & \phi_{22}
\end{matrix} \right|$$

How did they arrive at this step...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\left| 
\begin{matrix}a_{11}\phi_{11} + a_{21}\phi_{21} & a_{11}\phi_{12}+a_{21}\phi_{22} \\
\phi_{21} & \phi_{22}
\end{matrix} \right|=
\left| 
\begin{matrix}a_{11}\phi_{11} & a_{11}\phi_{12} \\
\phi_{21} & \phi_{22}
\end{matrix} \right|+\left| 
\begin{matrix}a_{21}\phi_{21} & a_{21}\phi_{22} \\
\phi_{21} & \phi_{22}
\end{matrix} \right|=\\
=
a_{11}\left| 
\begin{matrix}\phi_{11} & \phi_{12} \\
\phi_{21} & \phi_{22}
\end{matrix} \right|+a_{21}\underbrace{\left| 
\begin{matrix}\phi_{21} & \phi_{22} \\
\phi_{21} & \phi_{22}
\end{matrix} \right|}_{=0}.
$$
Here in the first two equalities we use the fact that the determinant is a linear function of the first row, and the last determinant beng zero we get since the matrix has two equal rows.